# Custom UITableViewCell crashing on [super dealloc]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, uitableview

I have a subclass of a UITableViewCell which is crashing when it hits the [super dealloc] line. I have several textFields in my cell and the error message is saying `*** -[UITextField release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x739dfd0`

The relevant code snippets are below (I do have other textFields but they are all treated the same way. My suspicion is it is to do with adding it to the contentView of the cell. But I do not know how to correct it.

.h file of Custom UITableViewCell:

```
@interface ExerciseTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    UITextField *textField1;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textField1;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation ExerciseTableViewCell

@synthesize textField1;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    UIView *myContentView = self.contentView;

        UITextField *newTextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];

        self.textField1 = newTextField1;

        [newTextField1 release];

        [myContentView addSubview:textField1];

    }
    return self;
}


}

- (void)dealloc {
    [textField1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I cannot see why I would be releasing the textField one too many times?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
UITextField *newTextField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init];

self.textField1 = newTextField1;

[newTextField1 release];

[myContentView addSubview:textField1];
```

to:

```
self.textField1 = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
[myContextView addSubview:self.textField1];
```

Comment: should I then release it in dealloc as well (to counter the retain in the .h file)?

Comment: Yes you should. Setting it by self.textField1 calls the setter, which retains it because you have declared it with retain attribute, then you're responsible to release it (your dealloc implementation is correct). Offtopic: when adding it to the contentView as a subview also retains the text field, but you're not responsible for its memory management, but the contentView is..

Comment: ...still not working. I understand what you have said and it makes perfect sense. There must be something else going on here.

Comment: Is this the only code? btw it's a good practice to @synthesize textField1 = _textField1; -this way your instance variable will be _textField1 and your property self.textField1 and it will be less confusing.. (in the dealloc you should - [_textField1 release]) and you can remove the instance variable in the .h file.. synthesize makes it for you...

Comment: i do have other code, but its setting delegates and positing the textFields. No memory management code in there. (Didn't want to clog up the question). How likely is it that the issue lies in the tableviewcontroller? I feel my custom cell is pretty vanilla! Re: the _textField1. I have seen this convention before but never fully understood it. Ill look into it more as you have mentioned it.

Comment: Btw check if you're not setting this property to nil (instead of setting the cell.textField1.text to nil for example) somewhere outside this class, for ex. where you create it...

Answer (score 1):

what is the need of declaring textfield locally and assigning it to the globally declared text field, just use

```
textField1 = [[UITextField alloc] init]; 
[myContentView addSubview:textField1];
```

Comment: This will still leak. When you assign to a retained property, you have to either `autorelease` or `release` the object afterwards, because the setter of the property already retains it (that is, if you're not using ARC, which the OP isn't).

Comment: he is already releasing it in dealloc method in his code, thats why i have not released it

Comment: Yes, but he would have to release it twice with this code. `alloc` returns a retained reference and the setter (`self.textField1 = ...`) also retains it (because the property is declared as `retain`).

Comment: Oops, now that you mention it, yes, I think so. I was a bit confused here, it seems, sorry.

Comment: @sreecharan Yes, the code you posted the first time was correct. In addition, for me it's the right way to do it since also Apple doc suggests to avoid using *self.someProperty* in *init* and *dealloc*. Obviously, calling *release* in *dealloc* it's necessary to avoid leaks.

Comment: @Ben Thompson watch **Flex_Addicted** comment, dont use self.someProperty

Answer (score 0):

Set textfield object to nil instead of releasing it. Second, please use a proper naming convention while coding.

Comment: Ill try that thanks. As for naming convention - I haven't actually used textField1, it was just easier when posting on SO to shorten and abbreviate the relevant code chunks.

Comment: that has worked. However, I feel as though this should be leaky. I have a retain in my .h file, so surely I need a release in my dealloc method?

Comment: if you do `self.textField1 = nil;` that will release it (as a setter releases the current value and then set the new value (in this case nil)). But it's been said that using accessors and setters in dealloc  can create problems. The usual way is to do `[textField1 release];` as you've done